# Generating random ARGB images doesn't produce images that can be opened

Tags: java, png

I am trying to generate random arrays and save them as argb images. However, when I do this, when I open the `.png` images, the images are blank, as if they all had an alpha of 0, regardless of the software I use to open them. This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class RandomColour
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;
        int arr[] = new int[w*h];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * 254);
            int g = (int) (Math.random() * 254);
            int b = (int) (Math.random() * 254);
            arr[i] = 0xFF000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }
        BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        WritableRaster raster = outputImage.getRaster();
        raster.setSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, arr);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, "png", new File("output.png"));
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Finished generating a random image.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code mainly looks good. The problem is the usage of `raster.setSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, arr)`. Note the second last parameter (self-explanatory named `b` ) which is "band". This means your code only sets samples for band 0, which is the R or red component in this case.

If you change this one line to:

```
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, arr);
```

your code will work as expected, and the PNG will contain random "static" noise. No other changes needed.

PS: This only works if your image is `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, as `setDataElements` assumes an array in the same format as the raster's transfer type.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem!